# Run a loop in GPU memory in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, pytorch

I am trying to slide a 224x224 sized window across an image, make a prediction and apply a helper_mask to the prediction.

```
patch_size = 224
result = torch.zeros((patch_size, patch_size), dtype=torch.long).cuda()  # 0: fn, 1: tp, 2: fp
image_c = image.cuda()   # load the tensor of an image to GPU
helper_mask_c = helper_mask_tensor.cuda()   # load the helper mask to GPU

for h in range(image_c.size()[2]- patch_size):
    for w in range(image_c.size()[3]- patch_size):
        # predict a mask of a part of an image
        mask = model(image_c[:,:,h:h+patch_size, w:w+patch_size])
        # normalize the predicted mask to 0 or 1
        mask = torch.clamp(mask.sigmoid().data * 2, min=0, max=1).to(torch.int)[0,0,:,:]
        # Apply helper mask to the prediction
        result[:, :] += mask * helper_tensor_c[h:h + patch_size, w:w + patch_size]
my_result = result.cpu().numpy()
```

These loops are generating `h` and `w` variables on the CPU rather than the GPU, which slows down the computation. What is the right way to load these loops to GPU to speed up the computation?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have overlapping patches?

Comment: Looks like a sophisticated way to do image convolution with global average pooling after it.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov I am studying the distribution of the model accuracy across the input layer.

Comment: @Ivan The goal of this study is to see the distribution of the accuracy across the input field of the model. It is not about "is this a pixel of a cat or a dog", rather, I want to know "how likely is it for a model to predict the pixel correctly, depending on the location of the of the pixel on the input layer"

Comment: What is the shape of `image_c`?

Comment: @Ivan this is a pytorch tensor of size (num_of_images, cannels, height, width). In my case (1, 3, 224, 224) because I send a single RGB image to the model. The result is (num_of_images, height, width), in my case (1,224,224).